# Avoiding autoconnection to "free" WiFi networks

Tags: wireless-networking, networkmanager

I'm using Linux with NetworkManager.

I want to allow auto-connection to WiFi networks only if the networks want a password. I want to avoid auto-connection to "free" networks, but manually initiated connection should be still possible.
How can I configure the NetworkManager ?